# ASP.NET How to get the URL's parameters before post to the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

that action

```
localhost:39217/SomeAction/
```

returns the whole list from the DB

If I proceed using the URL

```
localhost:39217/SomeAction/#someId?p=2
```

I want to return only the 2nd page from the DB. But I still get the whole list. Why ?

Here's my Action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int p = 1) //the `p` is always 1, even if I pass that 2nd URL
{
...
}
```

Comment: You are obviously going to have to replace `...` with your actual code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: int the `...` I just filter the `Select` query based on the `p` number

Comment: I have no idea what a "Select query" is.  However, you need to show us how you are consuming parameter `p` in order for us to help you.  Why don't you show us that code?

Comment: ...which is probably where the issue is.

Comment: Side comment: This question is not phrased properly. Intercepting the url route parameters *before* the controller is constructed is far more complex then "`Select` query based on the `p` number".

Comment: You don't understane me. If I pass that 2nd URL, the `p` argument passed to the Action should be 2, but it is 1

Comment: RPM1984 You're right, it works

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd URL is messed up.

Querystring parameters must go before anchors.

Try:

> localhost:39217/SomeAction?p=2#someId

Comment: OK, but I e.g I set the URL hash using `window.location.hash = 'someId' + '?p=2'`. If I proceed by that URL to the other browser's tab, the URL should be like You've answered to get the server's filtering works

Comment: @user1215114 - not sure what your talking about. You need to explain yourself a little better.